# Are refs guaranteed to be set when useEffect runs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set volume on an audio element, after it mounts.

If I have a ref on a DOM node, that isn't conditionally rendered, can I rely on that ref's value being defined once the first useEffect runs?

```js
function Component() {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Can ref.current ever be undefined here?
    ref.current.volume = 0.4;
  }, []);

  return <audio src="..." ref={ref} />
}
```

I've seen a lot of people put if statements and optional chaining for refs inside useEffect. Is that necessary if there's no conditional rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`refs` are set [during](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#when-react-attaches-the-refs) *commit phase*:

> React sets ref.current during the commit. Before updating the DOM,
> React sets the affected ref.current values to null. After updating the
> DOM, React immediately sets them to the corresponding DOM nodes.

And `useEffect` runs [after](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) *commit phase*:

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is
> committed to the screen. Think of effects as an escape hatch from
> React’s purely functional world into the imperative world.

so assuming you actually rendered that element on UI, `ref.current` should be referring to the DOM node inside effect.