# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classlist') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classlist')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

This is the travel site I am trying to build. The code is as follow

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Button } from "reactstrap";
import logo from "../../assets/images/logo.png";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./header.css";

const nav_links = [
  {
    path: "/home",
    display: "Home",
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    display: "About",
  },
  {
    path: "/tours",
    display: "Tours",
  },
];

const Header = () => {
  // const headerRef = useRef(null);

  // const stickyHeaderFunc = () => {
  //   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  //     if (
  //       document.body.scrollTop > 80 ||
  //       document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80
  //     ) {
  //       headerRef.current.classList.add("sticky__header");
  //     } else {
  //       headerRef.current.classList.remove("sticky__header");
  //     }
  //   });
  // };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   stickyHeaderFunc();

  //   return () => {
  //     window.removeEventListener("scroll", stickyHeaderFunc);
  //   };
  // }, []);

  const headerRef = useRef(null);

  const stickyHeaderFunc = () => {
    if (
      document.body.scrollTop > 80 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80
    ) {
      headerRef.current.classList.add("sticky__header");
    } else {
      headerRef.current.classList.remove("sticky__header");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", stickyHeaderFunc);

    return () => {
      // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", stickyHeaderFunc);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <header className="header" ref={headerRef}>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <div className="nav__wrapper d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            {/* _______Logo_________ */}
            <div className="logo">
              <img src={logo} alt="" />
            </div>
            {/* _______End of Logo_________ */}
            {/* _______Menu_________ */}
            <div className="navigation">
              <ul className="menu  d-flex align-items-center gap-5">
                {nav_links.map((item, index) => (
                  <li className="nav__item" key={index}>
                    <NavLink
                      to={item.path}
                      className={(navClass) =>
                        navClass.isActive ? "active__link" : ""
                      }
                    >
                      {item.display}
                    </NavLink>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
            {/* _______End of Menu_________ */}
            <div className="nav__right d-flex align-items-center gap-4">
              <div className="nav__btns d-flex align-items-center gap-4">
                <button className="btn secondary__btn">
                  <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </button>
                <button className="btn primary__btn">
                  <Link to="/Register">Register</Link>
                </button>
              </div>
              <span className="mobile__menu">
                <i class="ri-menu-line"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

The error message is as follows:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classlist')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classlist')
at http://localhost:3000/main.f7f4f4af7c19cb9b057e.hot-update.js:51:27

I am new to coding still a long way to go.. So please help

I am using to get the sticky bar with UseRef, not sure of the error message

Comment: The simplest solution is to use optional chaining... `headerRef.current?.classList.add()`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you're seeing ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-taussig-l4cdfd?file=/src/App.tsx. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75088534/283366) indicates that refs should be set by the time your effect hook runs which seems to be the case in the sandbox

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are trying to access the property `classList` on the ref object `headerRef`, which is `null` by default. The error code you listed is essentially telling you that you can't call `null.classList` because `null` can't have any properties.

In short, you need some additional logic to prevent your code from trying to access `null.classList`. Optional chaining would be the cleanest solution, e.g. `headerRef.current?.classList`, but there are a bunch of other ways to do it too.

You can also go into your useEffect and prevent `stickyHeaderFunc` from running unless `headerRef.current` exists.